# TFS 2010: Perform different builds and command line task in sequence?

Tags: msbuild, build-automation, installshield

my build process with TFS 2010 should perform different task one after the other like:

1. Build 1st project in solution
2. Execute MSBuild via command line (to publish the project)
3. Execute a 3rd party tool via command line (to obfuscate the binaries)
4. Build a 2nd project in the solution (an InstallShield project)

How can I achieve this? I can define several project in the Build Definition but how can I invoke several command line task between these build steps? And the MSBuildArguments in the Build Definition: Are these arguments for every msbuild call for each project/solution?

Thanks

Konrad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, you need to add in your build definition the distinct `*.*proj` instead of one big `*.sln` - or (even better) construct more than one `*.sln` & order them to get build in the build definition. 
So you could organize a `Project1.sln`, `Project2.sln` etc that are only used from the Build.
In addition to that, you would have to make changes in the build process template to get this.
By default you get something like that, that executes each set project/solution within a bigger `foreach`:
[image]

A good way would be to enhance this as a sequence, where all your custom action are set as `InvokeProcess` activities:
[image]

Obviously, you would have to insert here a flow control, so that `Publish` & `Dotfuscator` execute the first time (where `Project1.sln` gets build), while `ISDEV` executes the second time (where `Project2.sln` gets build). In the sample below I used a `switch` & packed `Publish` & `Dotfuscator` in a new `Sequence`.
Finally, you would have to have a counter of some sort. The most immediate option is to set a new Int32 Variable with default == 1 and increase it by hand during execution. In the sample below this is done in the lower `Assign`:
[image]

This final override of `Complie the Project`, along with a changed Build Definition should get what you 're after.

Answer (score 1):

The team build definition takes a list of sln's and msbuild project files.  You can put simply split your InstallShield project out into it's own solution ( most developers won't have a copy of InstallShield anyways likely ) and write an msbuild targets file for steps 2 and 3.   Then just tell your build definition to build solution 1, the targets file and solution 2.

You could also choose to put the stuff in the targets file in a postbuild event for one of the projects in solution 1.

I wouldn't do this in workflow.